# Pressure scanner for multi-hole Pitot-static probe going to 100km altitude and M3.5

Tags: pressure, aerospace-engineering

I am wondering if anyone has experience in looking for multi-channel differential pressure scanners for use with pitot static probes in aerospace? What companies/manufacturers/product familes would you recommend, as I am struggling to find any that meet all my requirements. My application requires differential pressure sensing up to 30 kPa of 7 pressure ports and absolute sensing of one port up to 1bar with accuracies <= 0.1% FS. As the max altitude is 100km it must be able to output differential measurements in essentially a vacuum (0.5kPa static pressure). As far as I can tell this requires the use of a true differential scanner, as absolute scanners generally have a lower pressure limit.

Space and weight are a concern (ideally <<250 grams), hence why I am opting to look for multi-channel pressure scanners rather than individual pressure sensors. These are the companies I have found so far that almost meet my requirements but not quite:

- [Chell Instruments NanoDAQ-LTS model](https://chell.co.uk/pressure/pressure-scanners/nanodaq-lt-series-pressure-scanners/nanodaq-lts-16-and-32-channel-slim-line-pressure-scanner/): This is a 16 channel absolute pressure scanner with great size, weight, accuracy values. However, lower pressure limit of 12 kPa, so can only work up to 15km altitude.
- [EvoScann P8-D](https://www.evoscann.com/product/true-differential-pressure-scanner/): 8 channel true differential model with good accuracy, weight, and space, but only rated up to 20 kPa differential pressure.
- [Microscanner 16MS](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-CAT-SCS0013.html): 16 channel. Unsure if this is true differential or absolute, but seems to require a data system to interface with (big and bulky, dont meet weight requirement)
- [Texense 8xPDIF-S](https://sensores-de-medida.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/TEXENSE-8xPDIF-S.pdf): 8 channel true differential, but ±0.5% FS accuracy, ±0.7% hysteresis, ±0.5% drift. So not accurate enough.
- [Keller series PD-10LX](https://keller-druck.com/en/products/pressure-transducers/oem-differential-pressure-transducers/series-pd-10l): Single differential pressure sensor model. good accuracy and reasonable size but accuracy is only rated down to 10 kPa line pressure.

Any extra manufacturers or products I might not have considered would be greatly appreciated! Or if you have worked a similar problem before and think that it is only solvable if I relax a requirement (e.g. size, weight, accuracy, pressure limit etc) please let me know.